# Laravel Scope get request data/param

Tags: php, comparative-review, laravel, eloquent

I want to pass the param from the request on the scope method in the model and serve it as json to be rendered by select2. Which is better?

#### 1. Pass request from the controller like this

controller:

```
public function selectJson(Request $request)
{

    $request = Customer::getSelect2($request)


    return \Response::json($request);
}
```

model:

```
public function scopeGetSelect2($query, $request)
{
    $customers = $query->select('id','name')->orderBy('name','asc')->where("name", "like", "%".$request->q."%");

    if($request->city_id)
    {
        $customers = $query->where("city_id", $request->city_id);

    }
    $customers = $customers->limit(5)->get();
    $formatted_tags = [];

    foreach ($customers as $customer) {
        $formatted_tags[] = ['id' => $customer->id, 'text' => $customer->name];
    }

    return $formatted_tags;
}
```

#### 2. Use request() helper in the model

Controller:

```
public function selectJson()
{

    $request = Customer::getSelect2()


    return \Response::json($request);
}
```

Model:

```
public function scopeGetSelect2($query)
{
    $customers = $query->select('id','name')->orderBy('name','asc')->where("name", "like", "%".request()->q."%");

    if($request->city_id)
    {
        $customers = $query->where("city_id", request()->city_id);

    }
    $customers = $customers->limit(5)->get();
    $formatted_tags = [];

    foreach ($customers as $customer) {
        $formatted_tags[] = ['id' => $customer->id, 'text' => $customer->name];
    }

    return $formatted_tags;
}
```

Which is better in performance and best practice? And should I format the return in the model like above codes or in the controller like below:

```
public function selectJson()
{

    $customers = Customer::getSelect2()->limit(5)->get();
    $formatted_tags = [];

    foreach ($customers as $customer) {
        $formatted_tags[] = ['id' => $customer->id, 'text' => $customer->name];
    }

    return \Response::json($formatted_tags);
}
```

Or any other method or concern that I need to know?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Laravel scopes are not a way to create static methods, they should be used to add parts to a database query. [They should always return a query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes).

Aim to make your scopes as small as possible so you can then combine them together to make more complex queries.

It doesn't matter if you use the `Request` passed in to the controller or the `request()` helper, use whichever you prefer.

If you aren't going to reuse the `getSelect2()` method you don't need to add it to the model, just do the query in the controller. If you do need to repeat the query elsewhere you can make a new class that can build the options (`$formatted_tags`).

```php
class Customer extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function scopeNameLike($query, $name): void
    {
        $query->orderBy('name','asc')->where("name", "like", "%{$name}%");
    }

    // ...
}
```

```php
class Controller
{
    public function selectJson(Request $request)
    {
        return Customer::nameLike($request->q)
            ->when($request->city_id, function ($query, $value) {
                $query->where('city_id', $value);
            })
            ->limit(5)
            ->get(['name', 'id'])
            ->map(function ($item) {
                return ['id' => $item->id, 'text' => $item->name];
            });
    }
}
```

---

> Is return something in scope really bad practice? What about the normal method in the model? I have so many tables/models that I need to format to select2 format. Am I need to format it in every controller? – Muhammad Dyas Yaskur

I was mistaken that scopes shouldn't return a value, as per the Laravel documentation they [should return a query builder instance](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes). It would be bad practice to return any other value from a scope.

If you need many of these types of queries for different models you can create a helper class that can then be reused.

```php
class Select2
{
    public static function customer(Request $request)
    {
        // Query moved from controller
    }
}
```

```php
class Controller
{
    public function selectJson(Request $request)
    {
        return Select2::customer($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is return something in scope really bad practice?  What about the normal method in the model? I have so many tables/models that I need to format to select2 format. Am I need to format it in every controller?

Comment: okay, thank for your explanation,  I have so many models that I need to select2 format, should I declare static method every model?  What about using a trait like on my another question?
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244071/using-method-trait-to-return-something-in-laravel-model