# Using method trait to return something in laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, trait

I have [question about scope](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244007/laravel-scope-get-request-data-param) yesterday, and someone gives an answer to don't return anything in scope. Is return something in scope really bad practice?  Should I not return anything in the model except query?

Rather than scope, I want to create a normal method to return the select2 format. I have so many model/table that I need to return to select2 format, I think it's WET (write every time) if I must write every model or controller. I think I need to use DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) principle, so I want to use a trait like below:

```
trait ModelTrait
{
    public static function getSelect2format($column = "name")
    {
        $data = static::select('id', $column.' as text')->orderBy($column, 'asc')->where($column, "like", "%".request()->q."%");

        if (is_array(request()->filter) && !empty(request()->filter)) {
            foreach(request()->filter as $key => $val)
            {
                if(in_array($key,$this->filterable))
                {
                    $data = $data->where($key, $val);
                }

            }
        }
        $data      = $data->limit(5)->get();

        return $data;
    }
}
```

I just need to call `use ModelTrait` in every model that I need and call it in the controller like below:

```
public function selectJson()
{

    $data = Customer::getSelect2Format("column_name");


    return \Response::json($data);
}
```

Is the code above break the best practice?
What are the concerns or something that I need to improve?

Comment: I'm sorry to inform you that your code is not working as intended. You cannot call a non-static method statically. Well actualy you can, but you will get a fatal error if the method uses `$this`. Your method uses `$this` on the very first line of its body. Not working code is off-topic on this site.

Comment: @slepic Sorry, Actually I have not tested it. Now I tested it and it's working, just changed the method type to static and ``$this`` to ``static::`` , Hope you can improve more, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have question about scope yesterday, and someone gives an answer to don't return anything in scope. Is return something in scope really bad practice?

- This is because laravel is handling "it" for you.
- getSelect2Format is not the best name since you are not handling formatting but apply a specific set of rules relevant to select2 js plugin.
- I would suggest a repository class or a helper class to handle this task.
- Your code is messy, very long lines too, which is hard to read! I would suggest following PSR-12.
- I would suggest using `response()` or just `return $data` in controller class methods.
- I would also suggest early returns in your methods to reduce nesting hence easy reviewing by reviewers.
- suggest not using `->get()` in a method unless you are absolutely certain on what method should do. i.e. you might want to apply a scope to this query  later on.
- I suggest passing request data into the class to make it easier to test. Also, the less your class knows about other parts of the system the better.
- Dont you have to use DB::raw for `$column.' as text'`?

```
class select2Filters
{
    public static function apply(
        Model $model, 
        array $data, 
        string $column = 'name', 
        int $limit = 5
    ) {
        $filter = Arr::get($data, 'filter');
    
        return $model::selectRaw(['id', "{$column} as text"])
             ->where($column, 'like', "%{$data['q']}%")
             ->when(is_array($filter), function($query) use ($filter) {
                 $query->where(Arr::only($filter, $model::filterable)); 
             })
             ->orderBy($column, 'asc')
             ->limit($limit)
             ->get();
    }
}
```

I would also suggest adding an interface to each model that should have support for `select2Filters`. That interface should inforce `filterable` variable.

I would personally not use `static`, that way you can add configuration methods, i.e. setLimit(). OR use data struct class to contain data needed for `select2Filters` class.

Comment: Thanks for your review, I like it. And sorry, my code was written when I write this question(without any ide/editor) so it's not formatted correctly. Usually, I use auto formatted to PSR12 using PhpStrom code formatted. And actually, I just created my own library for this case and also to learn or improve my skill, maybe I will create a question about that library. About PSR12, I have another question which maybe you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62480588/how-to-set-phpstorm-code-style-as-styleci-style-rule

Comment: Hi, I am afraid I have no idea on how to handle formatting in php storm, from what I know you meant to have a config which defines formatting and that configuration can be downloaded from the official psr website